Fastest way to find the absolute value of a double
Working on a Finite element solver for the fun of it, I encountered a math problem where the area of a triangle has to be solved multiple times for different triangular elements on a mesh.
Note: This is all being done in Cython:
For the 2D case, the determinant formula allows us to do this by the least number of arithmetic operations.
A = 0.5|[x_1(y_2-y_3) + x_2(y_3-y_1) + x_3(y_1-y_2)]|

However this will be called once for each element and, in the case of adaptive meshing, for every iteration too. So finding the absolute value becomes a problem. Going with a function that does comparisons and if-else branching seems wrong. So i thought that bit manipulation could be a solution here maybe and went with this approach.
from libc.stdint cimport uint64_t

cdef union DoubleIntUnion:
    double double_nr
    uint64_t int_nr

cdef double fastABS(double number) nogil:
    cdef DoubleIntUnion u_number
    u_number.double_nr = number
    u_number.int_nr &= <uint64_t>0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    return u_number.double_nr

this works. But is there any way to do it better in this case or any suggestions ?

...why wouldn't you just use abs?

where is the adventure in that ?

If you're looking for the most adventurous way to accomplish your task, that's not on-topic here.

Contrary to the popular belief, cryptic and obtuse code doesn’t necessarily mean better, and serves no purpose in establishing the coder as a highly-skilled individual.

The trouble with this kind of "optimization" is that the people writing the standard library (mostly) actually know what they're doing and would have written it that was themselves if it was faster.

If you just call std::abs, which inlines floating point number binary and to mask the sign bit, it would be challenging to beat it.
from libcpp.cmath cimport abs as std_abs

cdef double fastABS(double number) noexcept:
    return std_abs(number)


Your solution with union cast involves loading a SIMD register into a general purpose register, masking the sign bit, and loading the general purpose register back into SIMD register. Such loads are not cheap and best avoided.
Benchmark your variants to get full understanding.

It is so indeed. This code snippet performs almost exactly at double the speed of what i posted above. For reference on an array of 200000000 negative doubles:
my version -> 0.147358 sec
the std_abs -> 0.087069 sec
i am not sure where i am losing that CPU cycle

@MephistophelesFaust You lose CPU cycles on SIMD->GP->SIMD register transfers.

If you use regular abs on a numeric type then Cython automatically uses the C standard library abs to do it, so doing it explicitly shouldn't be necessary.

@DavidW std::abs gives you a nice compiler error if C standard library abs is not being called, compared to Cython abs.

@MaximEgorushkin that is true. Relying on Cython to do the right thing is always a bit opaque.

@DavidW More than that, if you declare std::abs, std::min, etc. yourself without that unnecessary except + exception specification, you always beat performance of Cython abs, min, etc.. Discovered that through examination of Cython-generated C++ code when performance of my code got worse after switching to Cython 3.0.

@MephistophelesFaust nogil for such a small function shouldn't be necessary, but it probably has non-zero cost. I have updated the solution to be even faster.
